# How to use text in a column with xyplot in R?

Tags: r

i have these data :

```
"","HH","Value"
"1","RR",59014
"2","RL",9076
"3","RU",12466
"4","LL",1304
"5","LR",8678
"6","LU",1912
"7","UL",1360
"8","UR",8662
"9","UU",15444
```

in my dataframe but when i try to do :

```
xyplot( Value ~ HH, data = datBeatRLU,
       xlab = "HH",
       ylab = "Value",
       main = "Who beat who ?"
)
```

I have an error.

```
Warning messages:
1: In order(as.numeric(x)) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In diff(as.numeric(x[ord])) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In (function (x, y, type = "p", groups = NULL, pch = if (is.null(groups)) plot.symbol$pch else superpose.symbol$pch,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Ho to simply indicate to xyplot to take this text or a dict with 1:RR 2:RL 3:RU etc ...

thanks and regards

Comment: "_I have an error._" What's the error?

Comment: `xyplot` is not a base R function. Please list any packages you are using in the body of your question.